# Axis, wsdlsoap:address location and reverse proxy

Tags: web-services, wsdl, axis, reverse-proxy

I've used AXIS 1.4 to generate some webservices.

These webservices will be called by clients, but their calls will go through a reverse proxy (apach with mod_proxy).

The process is working fine, however in the generated wsdl (when calling http://proxy/services/ServiceName?wsdl) axis generates the following block:

```
<wsdl:service name="MyService">
      <wsdl:port binding="impl:MyServicePortSoapBinding" name="MyServicePort">
         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://internalserver:8080/myapp/services/ServiceName"/>
      </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

The wsdlsoap:address still points to the internal, behind the firewall server - not the reverse proxy one. Although it does not seem to be a problem for my test clients at this stage, I'm wary of letting such information (servername, etc) public in the wsdl.

I've tried adding a `wsdlFile` tag in the `<service>` configuration in the `server-config.wsdd` file, pointing to a manually updated WSDL, without success (it keeps displaying the previous information).